# Как игнорировать в Linq значения, которые не конвертируются в double?

Tags: c#, linq

```
d = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(filename)
                .SelectMany(str => str.Split(new[] { ' ', '\t' },StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
                .Select(str => Convert.ToDouble(str.Replace('.', ',')))
                .ToArray();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Обновление**

Если вам нужно проверять числа из нескольких языков, проще делать это явно:

```
static CultureInfo englishCI = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US");
static CultureInfo russianCI = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("ru-RU");
```

```
.Select(s => double.TryParse(
                 s, NumberStyles.Float, englishCI,
                 out var de) ? de :
             double.TryParse(
                 s, NumberStyles.Float, russianCI,
                 out var dr) ? dr :
             (double?)null)
.OfType<double>()
.ToArray();
```

**Обновление**

Нашёл более изящный вариант:

```
.Select(s => double.TryParse(
                 s, NumberStyles.Float, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                 out var d) ? d : (double?)null)
.OfType<double>()
.ToArray();
```

---

По идее, вам нужно что-то такое:

```
.Select(s => double.TryParse(
                 s, NumberStyles.Float, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                 out var d) ? d : (double?)null)
.Where(v => v.HasValue)
.Select(v => v.Value)
.ToArray();
```

Пояснение:

1. Вам не нужно заменять точку на запятую для разбора чисел, вы должны вместо этого использовать правильную локаль. Иначе в незнакомой локали ваш код не будет работать.
2. В новой версии языка вы можете объявлять переменную прямо внутри `out`-клаузы.
3. В качестве маркерного значения лучше использовать то, которое не может встретиться в типе `doublе`. Я взял `null`, для этого пришлось расширить тип до `double?`. Возможно, можно было бы обойтись просто использованием `double.NaN`.
4. После фильтрации нужно «вернуться» от `double?` назад к `double`.

---

Для Visual Studio 2015 у вас не выйдет использовать `out var`, и придётся писать более длинно:

```
.Select(s =>
{
    double d;
    return double.TryParse(
               s, NumberStyles.Float, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
               out d) ? d : (double?)null;
})
.Where(v => v.HasValue)
.Select(v => v.Value)
.ToArray();
```

Comment: Чуть более красивее:  `.Where(v => v.HasValue)` вместо `.Where(v => v != null)`, хотя компилятор всё равно заменит ваше условие на `HasValue`.

Comment: @Nikita: Согласен, так изящнее. Заменил, спасибо!

Comment: @VladD Подскажите почему у меня не выходит использовать out var d?

Comment: @kovdryavlad для использования [этой фичи](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c%23/1936/c-sharp-7-0-features/6326/out-var-declaration#t=201704242203511676453) нужен компилятор C# 7, который идет в комплекте с Visual Studio 2017.

Comment: @kovdryavlad: Может быть, у вас старая версия Visual Studio? Нужна VS 2017.

Comment: @Nikita: Придумал ещё изящнее.

Comment: Стоит , наверное, отметить, что некоторые LINQ выражения не гарантируют вызов элемента 1 раз. Если не ошибаюсь, то сортировка может вызывать один и тот же элемент несколько раз=> при постоянном касте может просесть производительность.

Comment: @iluxa1810 нет, вы что-то путаете. Последовательность может быть обойдена целиком несколько раз - но никак не отдельные элементы.

Comment: @iluxa1810 в любом случае, .`ToArray()` - материализующий вызов

Comment: @VladD
Объясните пожалуйста, почему NumberStyles.Float, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture работает как-то через раз?
А str.Replace('.', ',') дает мне нужный результат.
Моя ситуация такова, что мне нужно читать файлы половина из которых содержит даблы через зяпятую, а вторая через точку. Мне нужно в любом случае все читать

Comment: @kovdryavlad: А что вы имеете в виду под «через раз»? Замена на запятую не будет работать, если запустить программу на английской системе.

Comment: @VladD 
Работает только для файлов с точкой.

Comment: @VladD Мне бы функцию, что позволит открывать файлы с даблами через точку и через запятую

Comment: @kovdryavlad: Написал ещё обновление.

Answer (score 2):

`Linq` не серебряная пуля, не стоит все делать через него, так почему бы не написать свой метод расширения? Может не самый лаконичный способ, но вполне рабочий и нет передачи `null`ов с последующей проверкой

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var l = new List<string>{"1.7", "1.3s", "1.3", "1.13"};
        l.ToEnString().ToList().ForEach(t=>Console.WriteLine(t));
    }
}

static class Ex
{
    public static IEnumerable<double> ToEnString(this IEnumerable<string> arg)
    {
        foreach (var str in arg)
            if (double.TryParse(str, out var d))
                yield return d;
    }
}
```

Comment: А еще лучше передать проверяющую функцию в качестве параметра ;) То есть получить что-то вроде [`Seq.choose`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/seq.choose%5b't,'u%5d-function-%5bfsharp%5d) из `F#`

Answer (score 1):

Если файл не предполагает наличие нулевых значений (`default(double)`), то можете воспользоваться методом `Double.TryParse()`:

```
d = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(filename)
                .SelectMany(str => str.Split(new[] { ' ', '\t' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
                .Select(str => {
                    Double value;
                    var isParsed = Double.TryParse(str.Replace('.', ','), out value);

                    if (isParsed)
                        return value;
                    else
                        return default(double);
                })
                .Where(d => d != default(double))
                .ToArray();
```